# how to create a url like wordpress in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I have a URL like this

http://localhost/my_app/class/function/sample-post

and want to change like this

http://localhost/my_app/2015/06/09/sample-post/

Comment: You can create routes in config/routes.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in application/config/routes.php

```
$route["(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/sample-post"] = "class/function/$1/$2/$3";
```

thus all urls like this pattern will route to Controller 'class' and method 'function' , and also you can find year, month, date in 3 arguments, according to date you can show output.

if you need more about routing read https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html